# Please help me recover my ringtones after an iPhone restore

Tags: restore, ringtones

I downloaded ringtones from iTunes a couple weeks ago.  I don't think I ever synced my iPhone since, but I did have to reset my iPhone due to an application crash.

When I got my iPhone restored from a backup, my ringtones were gone and the only way to prove that I ever had them was through the receipt that Apple sent to my email account.

I tried finding them on "purchased" in my iTunes account but there was nothing there.

How can I retrieve my ringtones?

Answer (score 1):

Found over [here](http://mobiles.bigresource.com/Track/mobiles-uUgpV2Uwj/):

With iPhone connected to computer:

- In iTunes menu select "Store," then "Deauthorize Computer"
- Then select "Store," then "Authorize Computer"
- A message will pop up saying "X out of X Computers are Authorized" or something to that effect.
- Sync iPhone
- Restart iPhone, go to settings, sounds, ringtones. Purchased ringtone should be on top.